# fs.existsSync is not a function in a create-react-app project?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): fs__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.existsSync is not a function
```

I've a project created with create-react-app, when I call a method in fs module, it raises an error.

```
import * as fs from "fs"

const doesPathExist = fs.existsSync(this.inputPath);
```

Comment: fs is a core nodejs module, I don't think you can use it inside a react app.

Comment: ya you need to add your functionality in your node.js (server-side).

Comment: As others said `fs` is a node server only feature and can't be bundled for a browser package. The question is why are you trying to bundle it for the browser?

Comment: I've a jack compiler, which I built it in the nand2tetris.org course, so now I want to build a simulator in react that shows how a compiler works. So my program first reads the .jack file.

Comment: Consider putting the contents in a variable in a js file (e.g. `export const jack = '....';`) and then you can use `import { jack } from 'the file'` so the actual content is included in the bundle

Comment: Yeah, I can do that for now, but that is not the generic way, I think.

Comment: Take a look at https://webpack.js.org/loaders/raw-loader/ might have what you are looking for (replace the .txt for the .jack and the principle should be the same). You could even write a custom loader if you want to process the file when loading it as well